# How to use WPF's asterisk size value in codebehind?

Tags: wpf, code-behind, gridlength

I create some control in codebehind and would like to set its size dynamically.
I can assign numerical values as well as `System.Windows.GridLength.Auto`, but there is no equivalent to `"*"`.
Is that because the `"*"` from XAML gets translated into code when the WPF gets parsed?

To give this some detail: There is a grid with three rows. I want the top and bottom row to take all the space they can, while the middle row remains auto-sized.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
var gridLength = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

More info: [`GridUnitType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridunittype) enum.